# My form is submitting automatically even validations shows errors in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm using Bootstrap validations to my webform in asp.net, I'm using HTML controls only. When I'm submitting the form the form is submitted even the validation fails. I don't know why it is happening like that.

I'm actually very new to this Bootstrap validations. I had started using this validations through following link http://formvalidation.io/download/. Here what I'm trying to say is when I submit my form first it has to check the validations and if the validations are gone perfect then it has to submit the form to the server. If there is any field is blank then the form should not be submitted.

I had searched about this problem on the web, but I can't understand what they are actually saying. I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery, here is the links they suggested:

[http://formvalidation.io/examples/cant-submit-form-after-validation/](http://formvalidation.io/examples/form-submit-twice/)

Here I'm using asp.net c# to send the values to the server.

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" runat="server" />
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form1').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',        
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            user: {
                row: '.col-lg-3',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter username'
                    },
     regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        message: 'user Name Should be Alphabets'
                    }
                }
            },
   pass: {
                row: '.col-lg-3',
                validators: { 
                  notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter password'
                    },
     regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/,
                        message: 'pass Should be Alphabets'
                    }
                }
            }
            }
    });    
});
```

```js
 protected void submit_ServerClick1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Redirect("home.aspx",false);
      }
```

Comment: You can use simple script and use client click on button, it will solve your problem.. Just find javascript validation in google..

Comment: can you please give me any example to restrict the form submission if validation fails and then submit the form if validation success.

Comment: you need to set `CausesValidation = true` for the validation to work on the button property

Comment: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/10/javascript-user-registration-form-validation-source-code.html

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/Asp-Net-form-validation-using-javascript/

Comment: @surya if u find solution helpful then you should mark with helpful flag so others can get info if they have similar problem..